# What does it mean to combine interact with return in expect?

Tags: shell, expect

I want to use shell and expect to log in to the server with only one command. 
But when interact and return are used in one statement, I don't understand what they mean.In addition, "Password" will only appear when SSH link multiplexing is disconnected, so I hope that when "Password" does not appear, it will not send "mypassord".

1. So how to write scripts to deal with these two situations in a unified way?
2. When SSH multiplexed links were established, my script was stuck in "expect "*Password*"".How to deal with it?
3. In addition, I would like to ask what does the -o parameter mean after the interact? And what is the meaning of using interact and return together?
4. What's the difference between "send --" and "send "?

I have enabled SSH master connection. Before I log on to the server, I need to first enter the password, and then enter a number to represent which machine I log on to. But when SSH multiplexed links are established, the option of entering passwords becomes redundant.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# ssh command
set cmd [lindex $argv 0]
set relay_num [lindex $argv 1]

set timeout -1

# run ssh command
spawn bash -c "$cmd"

expect "Password*"
send "mypassord\r"

interact -o -nobuffer -re "Option" return
send -- "$relay_num\r"

interact
```

Comment: Using `send -- $variable` is good practice if the contents of `variable` are unpredictable.  If you do `send $variable` and `variable`'s value happens to start with `-` the `send` command will try to interpret it as an option.  Adding the option `--` first avoids this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In combination with the `-o` switch, that line is looking at the output of the command for the regex "Option". The `return` will cause the `interact` command to end and the script continues to the `send` command (that is explained in the man page).

I think it would be more clear to use `expect "Option"` instead.